# Matlab: How to write a function that gets an integer n and always returns the result P = 1*1.2*1.4*....*(1+0.2*(n-1))

Tags: matlab, function, sequence

I am trying to solve a problem that requires writing a function called repeat_prod(n), that gets an integer n and returns the result of the following function:

P = 1*1.2*1.4*....*(1+0.2*(n-1))

for exemple if n is 6:

```
repeat_prod(6)

ans = 9.6768
```

I tried the following:

```
function P = repeat_prod(n)
  for 1:n-1
    P = (1+0.2*(n-1));
  end
end
```

But it does not run. How can I get the loop to work?

Comment: Do you know how to create `P`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works is that you show what you've already tried and explain what's not working. Post some code showing what you've tried. You're unlikely to get an answer to a (homework) question when you haven't shown any attempt to answer it yourself. Good luck! See [ask].

Comment: Please see the documentation of [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) and [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) and then give it a try. Let us know how it goes

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked, do you know how to create an array containing the values `[1, 1.2, 1.4...]`? From there it's just a matter of either looping through this array or using the `prod` function.

Comment: Sometimes it is a lot faster to find your solution by reading some [introductory material](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html) on the internet than asking a question on SO and waiting for people.

Comment: Thank you for giving me some direction beaker, really appreciate it!

Comment: Please [edit] this one with all relevant information, rather than reposting the same question. Please see [ask] in the [help] about that.

Comment: There are lots of examples here on how to use a `for` loop: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html — You will also have to start with `P=0`, and then add to it each loop iteration using `P=P+...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic within your function should be something like below

```
function P = repeat_prod(n)
  P = 1; % initial value for following cumulative products 
  for k = 1:n
    P = P*(1+0.2*(k-1));
  end
end
```

---

**Compact Version**

You can also use `prod` within your function `repeat_prod` to replace `for` loop, i.e.,

```
function P = repeat_prod(n)
  P = prod(1 + 0.2*((1:n)-1));
end
```